# Rails Syntax for traversing 2 Master Detail relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails Learner Driver Q.

DB Entities - 2 Master Detail relationships

Each City  has_many Hotels
Each Hotel has_many Rooms

Each Room  belongs_to Hotel
Each Hotel belongs_to City

I wake up in a Hotel Room - but how do i know which City I am in please?

@Room.hotel.name = the Hotel name

But what syntax can I use to refer to "Which City I am in ?"

in order to traverse 2 Master Detail relationships?

In Java would be simple as:
string cityName = room.gethotel().getcity().getname()

In Rails - is this achieved using   :through => :hotel  ?

Or that is only for defining Many to Many relationships.

Best answer for me would be to point to a Chapter in a Book that runs through all of this please?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Your java example is essentially the same concept; did you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

=========================================================

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association

=========================================================

```
has_one :city, through: :hotel

<%= @room.city.name %>
```

=========================================================

city.rb
  class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :hotels
  end

hotel.rb
  class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :city
    has_many :rooms
  end

room.rb
  class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :hotel
    has_one :city, through: :hotel
  end

views / rooms

show.html.erb
    <%= @room.city.name %>

index.html.erb
    <%= room.city.name %>

===================================================================